# How do i use subqueries in a left join as a table

Tags: mysql, cakephp, orm, subquery, cakephp-3.x

`Cakephp` informs me that it cannot find the table or does not recognize the alias what am i supposed to use?

Hello i am new to **cake php ORM** can any one tell me how to preform a left join on a subquery I'm really interested to know how to use in working the join
Here is sub query and left join so far please ignore any syntax error

```php
$scl = TableRegistry::get('School');
$subquery = $scl->find();

$subquery->select([
    'UID',
    'SID',
    'Total' => $subquery->func()->sum('numberOfStudents')
])->group(['UID, SID']);


$q->select([
    'TeacherID',
    'ClassID',
    'StudentTotal' => 'sq.Total'
])->join([
    'table' => $subquery,
    'alias' => 'sq',
    'type' => 'LEFT',
    'conditions' => ['sq.UID = TeacherID', 'sq.SID = ClassID']
]);
```

here is the error:

> [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sq.UID' in 'on clause'

Comment: I can't see where you defined $subquery?

Comment: Whenever you rceive an error, please post the complete, exact error message and include the corresponding stacktrace (ideally copied from the logs, where it is available in a readable fashion) - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that ORM based queries automatically alias the selected fields, so you don't get

```sql
SELECT UID, SID ...
```

but

```sql
SELECT UID as School__UID, SID as School__SID
```

hence referring to `sq.UID` will fail, as no such field name was selected.

To avoid this problem you can either use an alias that matches the original field name:

```php
->select([
    'UID' => 'UID',
    'SID' => 'SID',
    // ...
])
```

use the lower level database query that doesn't automatically create aliases:

```php
$subquery = $scl
    ->getConnection() // connection() in older CakePHP versions
    ->newQuery()
    ->from($scl->getTable()); // table() in older CakePHP versions
```

or refer to the aliased fields in the main query:

```php
'conditions' => [
    'sq.' . $scl->getAlias() . '__UID = TeacherID', // alias() in older CakePHP versions
    'sq.' . $scl->getAlias() . '__SID = ClassID',
]
```

Comment: Thanks you are a life saver. Much appreciated